# Is it safe to send sms via AsyncTask?

Tags: android

Suppose I have an ArrayList containing 10 numbers. While I iterate through the array from the ui thread, I send sms like :

```
new smsAsyncTask().execute(new String[]{number,message});

public class smsAsyncTask extends AsyncTask <String,Void,Void>{

@Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... data) {

            smsmanager.sendTextMessage(data[0], null, data[1], null, null);

            return null;

    }
```

What I wonder is if the user press return button before all sms have been sent, will the AsyncTasks be killed with the Activity ? Should I use ui thread instead of sending with AsyncTasks, I want the ui to stay as fast as possible.

Comment: If the user exits the `Activity` hosting the `AsyncTask` then there is a danger that the thread used for `doInBackground(...)` may become orphaned if you don't clean up properley (in `onPause()` for example). I'd probably use a `Service` of some sort (most likely an `IntentService`) rather than an `AsyncTask` or anything hosted by the `Activity` directly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would also suggest using a service which is more reliable than async task, async task is dependent on the activity being in the foreground.